# Does Hashem judge on Shabbos?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, theology

I was just reading a Devar Torah which said "Hashem does not judge human beings on Shabbos." I feel like I've heard this before but I'm wondering if this is true. Does anyone know of a primary source (Rishonim or earlier) that discusses whether Hashem judges on Shabbos? Thank you so much.

(This question is not about whether someone gets punished on Shabbos. It's only about whether Hashem judges on Shabbos.)

Comment: Rosh Hashana is on Shabbat in two months, fwiw.

Comment: The [gemarra](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3b.7?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that every day Hashem sits on His throne of Judgement and judges the whole world. Sounds like even on Shabbos?

Comment: What difference does it make if He does or doesn't?

Comment: B'Rosh Hashanah Yikaseivun but with a shinui I guess

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Its integral to the Vort I'm reading. Its also important to know for other reasons.

Comment: It could be because ein donin baShabbos

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly, I have heard this idea before (in a Drush sort of way) specifically because of Rosh Hashana falling out on Shabbos. I don't recall all the details (if I had to guess, I would say it's one of the Chassidic stories from R' Levi Yitzchak Miberditchev) but it went something like since Rosh Hashana is on Shabbos, Hashem isn't allowed to condemn us in judgement, but giving us a positive judgement is Hatzolas Nefashos, so therefore Hashem is 'forced' to judge us favorably on Shabbos Rosh Hashana.

Comment: Do you want to get all philosophical? After all, Hashem is lema'alah min hazman (beyond time). He doesn't Judge us on Shabbos because Shabbos is a period of time, and Hashem doesn't do time. I could write an answer about what "judging on Shabbos" or "on Rosh haShanah" etc... could mean, but seems far from what you intended to ask about.

Comment: @MichaBerger And yet the Machzor says that G-d judges on Rosh HaShanah. But looking at the language of the את חיל יום פקודה, alludes to the subject of judgement in thought. טרם כל מפעל חצב. יזם במחשבת צור חצב. And this follows the halacha as Rambam brings in the laws of Shabbat.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, I think we mean that we experience Divine Justice on RH. But this isn't the place for tangential discussions

Comment: We have an appointment to present ourselves for Judgment. How we respomd to that appointment impacts our whole year.

Comment: @MichaBerger Your last comment is a bullseye. I found your 1st comment directed to the OP pretty funny. He’s asking about G-d’s behavior in the Beit Din shel ma’aleh on Shabbat and you’re questioning whether he wants to get “all philosophical”!? It’s a great question but not simple & definitely very philosophical.

Answer (score 5):

I emailed my father and he helped me out.

The [Daas Zekeinim Mibaalei Hatosfos on Shemos 14:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Daat_Zkenim_on_Exodus.14.2.2?lang=he) is explicit that Hashem judges on Shabbos even though it's Assur for humans to:

> ולי נראה דדוקא לאדם אבל להקב"ה לא שהרי מצינו **שהקב"ה יושב ודן את כל העולם אפילו בשבת ואפילו בר"ה ויום הכפורים אע"פ שלישראל אסור** (וכה"ג כתב רש"י ז"ל בר"ה (דף ל' ע"א) ד"ה א"נ דאבני בליליא וכו' ה"מ בנין בני אדם וכו' יע"ש).

(Note that there is another answer there, but if you look into it you will see that it's not arguing this point.)

The [Mechilta](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d%27Rabbi_Yishmael.31.17.3?vhe=Mekhilta_--_Wikisource&lang=he) is also explicit that Hashem judges on Shabbos:

> מכילתא דרבי ישמעאל כי תשא - מסכתא דשבתא פרשה א - כי ששת ימים עשה ה' את השמים ואת הארץ וביום השביעי שבת. ממה שבת, מן העבודה, או אף מן הדין, תלמוד לומר וינפש, מגיד שאין הדין בטל מלפניו לעולם; וכן הוא אומר +תהלים פט טו+ צדק ומשפט מכון כסאך חסד ואמת יקדמו פניך, [וכתו' +שם /תהלים/ צז ב+ ענן וערפל סביביו צדק ומשפט מכון כסאו,] ואומר +דברים לב ד+ הצור תמים פעלו כי כל דרכיו משפט וגו'.

See also Mishnas Chaim from Rav Scheinberg (Beshalach 36) for more discussion why it's okay for Hashem to judge on Shabbos.

Comment: The speculation from the Da’at Zakeinim is not in disagreement with what I wrote, namely that the judgement on Shabbat is in thought. And his reference to Rashi is in regard to the building of the 3rd Temple. But according to Rashi, that Temple is complete (except for the doors) and stored in the Heavens. The concept of building doesn’t relate to it.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that the Mechilta you quote mentions before your citation that the prosecuting Angel (Plony) also keeps Shabbat. His market is closed and his business stopped. How do you have a trial and judgement without a prosecutor? This only underlines that this “judgement” by G-d on Shabbat is not actual judgement but only on the level of thought in compliance with the halacha as stated by Rambam. That the “writing of the judgement” is from the letters of thought only and the “sealing of judgement” is when they come to a state of actuality and realization.

Comment: And this follows the idea that when Rosh HaShanah falls on Shabbat we skip the recital of: תעיר ותריע. להכרית כל מריע. This is because the Prosecuting Angel is not present on Shabbat. There is no actual judgement.

Comment: And all this follows the general idea that we don’t blow shofar on Shabbat (see Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Shofar 2:6). The very act which confuses and overturns the case of the Prosecuting Angel is not done. This is because the actual judgement does not take place. On Shabbat it is only in thought.

Answer (score -5):

It's the plain meaning of the verse from Tehillim 147:19 which says:

> מַגִּ֣יד דְּבָרָ֣יו לְיַעֲקֹ֑ב חֻקָּ֥יו וּ֝מִשְׁפָּטָ֗יו לְיִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃

That all the laws and judgements in Torah which G-d commanded to the Jewish people are also observed by G-d. This follows one of the long-standing teachings the Lubavitcher Rebbe like is found for example in [Torat Menachem Hitvadiyut, vol. 3 from the year 5711, pg. 12 notes 26-27](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25035&st=&pgnum=10)

And like the Rebbe cites from [Yerushalmi Rosh HaShanah, chapter 1, Halacha 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Rosh_Hashanah.7b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> בנוהג שבעולם מלך בשר ודם גוזר גזירה. רצה מקיימה רצו אחרים מקיימים אותה **אבל הקב"ה אינו כן אלא גוזר גזירה ומקיימה תחילה מאי טעמא ושמרו את משמרתי אני ה' אני הוא ששימרתי מצותיה של תורה תחילה.**

This is the same sentiment that is also expressed by Rabbi Avin Bar Rav Adda in relation to tefillin as found in Berachot 6a, which says:

> Rabbi Avin bar Rav Adda said that Rabbi Yitzḥak said: From where is it derived that the Holy One, Blessed be He, wears phylacteries? As it is stated: “The Lord has sworn by His right hand, and by the arm of His strength”

And so the answer to your question should be found in the laws of Shabbat.

Rambam in Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Shabbat 24:7 which says:

> **[A court] may not punish on Shabbat.** Even though the punishment is a positive commandment, it does not override [forbidden types of work on] Shabbat. How is this? If one surely become liable for lashes or the death penalty, we neither give him lashes nor kill him on Shabbat; as it is stated (Exodus 35:3), "You may not kindle fire in all of your inhabitations on the Shabbat day"—this is a prohibition to the court that, on Shabbat, they not burn someone who became liable for burning. And the same is true with the other punishments.

However this raises the same question you raise. Does this prohibition only apply to *the execution* of the judgement or *the process of judgement* itself?

But if one considers the first halacha in that same chapter, the prohibition would seem to extend even to the judgement itself which would be like discussing with your business associates, meaning those Judges sitting with you on the Jewish court, what business to take up the next day.

In other words, actual **deliberation of the case and judgement**, while leaving the execution of the judgement until after Shabbat, **is also prohibited on Shabbat**.

Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Shabbat 24:1

> **Some acts are forbidden on the Sabbath even though they neither resemble nor lead to prohibited work.** Why then were they forbidden? Because it is written: "If you refrain from following your business on the Sabbath, on my holy day… If you honor it, not following your wonted ways, **not pursuing your business, nor speaking of it**" (Isaiah 58:13). Hence, **one is forbidden to go anywhere on the Sabbath in connection with his business, or even to talk about it.** Thus one must not discuss with his partner what to sell on the next day, or what to buy, or how to build a certain house, or what merchandise to take to such-and-such a place. All this, and the like, is forbidden, for it is written "nor speaking of it." That is to say, speaking of business on the Sabbath is forbidden; thinking of it, however, is permitted.

And it is worth noting that the last comment from Rambam in this halacha appears to be an insight into the judgement of Rosh Hashanah, for example, when it falls out on Shabbat. Rambam emphasizes that thinking about business matters is not prohibited on Shabbat.

And so, in context G-d could think about how a judgement would be deliberated in the Heavenly court and how it might resolve.

But this last concept needs to be understood in the context of the teaching of Eliyahu HaNavi that is found in the *[P'tach Eliyahu](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Shabbat_Eve_Mincha%2C_Mincha.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)* recited at Mincha of erev Shabbat. G-d's thoughts are not like our thoughts. From our perspective, G-d's thoughts are ***like*** a completed action, even though by G-d it is thought.

And this idea relates also to the concept of G-d judging someone unfavorably on Rosh HaShanah. And yet through our actions through the remaining cycle of Tishrei, that *judgement* can be overturned.

Comment: I wouldn't think the plain meaning of Tehillim 147:19 is that Hashem follows the Torah. Do you have anyone else who agrees with this reading? By the way, your source of Hashem wearing tefillin is a counter proof to your understanding. If we wore such tefillin, it would be pasul. Hashem wears pasul tefillin? Must be He doesn't follow the Torah...Also, I believe there's no prohibition for Beis Din to effect rulings on Shabbos. The Rambam just says they can't punish. Can they be mechayev someone money? I think it's only Rabbinic that they can't...so why can't Hashem?

Comment: But Hashem does carry out judgment on Shabbos.  People have good and ר"ל bad things happen to them on Shabbos.

Comment: @Heshy I take it you also are of the opinion that G-d doesn't keep Shabbat like we say at kiddush.

Comment: We say at kiddush that Hashem keeps Shabbos?

Comment: @robev That's when we recite, "The sixth day, etc." from the written Torah. יום הַשִּׁשִּׁי. וַיְכֻלּוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם וְהָאָרֶץ וְכָל צְבָאָם:
וַיְכַל אֱלהִים בַּיּום הַשְּׁבִיעִי מְלַאכְתּו אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה. וַיִּשְׁבּת בַּיּום הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּו אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה:

Comment: That doesn't mean He keeps it every week...maybe only that one time...

Comment: Are you of the opinion that things that happen to people on Shabbos are not a result of judgment?  That sounds like a much bigger contradiction with all of our sources.  And of course, you can set up a court on Shabbos for things that need to happen for that Shabbos: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.24.5

Comment: @robev If you raise a question in comments which I answer, please don’t delete my response. Like I wrote previously, the 7 days of creation mentioned in parshat Bereshit are the paradigm which repeats each weekly cycle. This idea is expressed in the blessings preceding the recital of Shema in the morning. It is also the idea expressed in the section of Zohar recited by many prior to the Shabbat evening Prayer.

Comment: @Heshy It would relate to the permissibility of thinking about business matters on Shabbat. G-d’s thoughts are like action to us. Nevertheless, by HaShem they are thoughts. And that is the teaching we have from Eliyahu HaNavi in P’tach Eliyahu.

Comment: Not a downvoter, and as it stands now, I believe this is a complete and valid answer, with the exception of the first line. You can't claim that it's 'the plain meaning' of a Passuk when you have to have an explanation from the Rebbe based off of a Yerushalmi to explain it. Is it a valid explanation? Sure. Is it the simple explanation? Absolutely not.

Comment: While we say המחדש הטובו בכל יום תמיד, I see zero indication from that that Hashem rests on Shabbos. I don't know what you mean by deleting your response. I also don't see why a judge metting out justice is called business

Comment: @Salmononius2 I am not relying on the Rebbe for the meaning of the words. Robev asked for me to provide some valid authority to support my initial statement that the plain meaning from the posuk in Tehillim was that G-d keeps the commandments. I gave a source from the Rebbe this a recognized expert on Rashi whose commentary is according to Peshat. The Rebbe says the plain meaning is as I state. I also pointed to two sources in the Oral Torah, Talmud Yerushalmi and also Talmud Bavli which present the same concept. "His laws and His judgements" is the Peshat. G-d abides by His commandments.

Comment: How in the world is that the plain meaning of the Posuk? The context is we're praising G-d for all the wonders he does, and one of them is (Sefaria translation) "He issued His commands to Jacob, His statutes and rules to Israel." It's praising G-d that He gave us the commandments, not that G-d follows the commandments. If the words were 'Maggid Devarav La'Elokim, Chukav Umishpatav Le'Atzmo' then you can argue that the 'plain meaning' is referring to G-d. But since it says 'Le'Yaakov' and 'Le'Yisrael', the plain meaning is obviously referring to the Jews. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Claiming otherwise is literally the opposite of the words 'plain meaning'! And for crying out loud, I just looked at the link you provided from Toras Menachem, and the words are literally 'Kidroshas Chazal Al Haposuk"! It says explicitly in your source that it's a Drasha, which is by definition not the simple reading! If it would be the simple reading, it would be the Pshat! Again, claiming that an interpretation of the Posuk is that Hashem keeps the Torah is perfectly fine, but claiming it's the plain meaning is completely wrong!

Comment: Also, please give a source to this Rashi you keep pointing to as saying the plain meaning refers to G-d. There is no Rashi linked to that Posuk on Sefaria (and that's besides for the fact that not all Rashi's are automatically Peshat. He does very often bring Drashos in his explanation as well)

Comment: @Salmononius2 The emphasis (and plain meaning) being that the His laws & judgements are His. G-d keeps His laws and judgements like is stated explicitly in the Yerushalmi and elsewhere. The word 'drasha' has many meanings, not just as in midrash. Check your Jastrow. I didn't say that Rashi made a comment. I said that the Rebbe is an expert on Rashi's style of commentary which is Peshat. If you read the link to the Rebbe's talk I provided, it is clear that he is saying the plain meaning (just like Rashi uses that style of explanation) of the posuk from Tehillim is as I stated.

Comment: The downvotes are because you added too much. If you just wrote "The Rebbe taught... as is explicit in the yerushalmi..." and then bring your chakira and the rambams, you'd be fine. I think you lost votes by claiming that the explanation of that pasuk is pashut pshat- which it clearly is not- and then doubling down by claiming that the rebbe said it is- which he doesn't say. All he brings (from what I've seen) is that chazal explain the passuk that way. it doesn't mean it's pashut pshat. If you could ask the rebbe today "is pshat that we're praising hashem for giving us his torah, or (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) stating that Hashem keeps His laws" so you could explain it to a baal teshuva who you're teaching, it's obvious he would say the former. And he would probably add that chazal add an additional understanding by teaching that He keeps His own laws as well." The rebbe would never say what you're saying. Likewise, like @robev pointed out, the gemara about tefillin isn't proof that he keeps the torah the way we do; if anything he does things differently than we do (white tefillin, different psukim) so maybe his shmiras shabbos is different as well. (BTW I didn't downvote.)

Comment: I thought the downvotes were because his readings of sources are unsubstantiated. Although he successfully showed that it's possible to understand that Hashem keeps the Torah (although what that means still needs clarification), he failed to show that executing justice on Shabbos is prohibited, to the point that Hashem Himself wouldn't do it. He made a jump from business discussions to discussing judgement, which is no worse than Talmud Torah.

Comment: @Binyomin מגיד דבריו ליעקב doesn’t mean ‘we’ praise. It translates as “He tells His words” meaning Chukim, to Yaacov. And the root is נגד as in to tell, like with the Haggadah on Pesach. It has nothing to do with praise which is a different root. The plain meaning (Peshat) of the words is as I have translated them.

Comment: @robev All these irrelevant arguments you keep offering have nothing to do with answering the question posed by the OP. If you have a separate question about what any of these statements mean according to the traditional teachings found in Torah, then ask a separate question. As you noted yourself, this question was legitimately answered. It shouldn't be getting flamed.

Comment: @YaacovDeane the whole perek is a praise of Hashem "He tells His words  to Yaakov, His chukim and mishpatim to Yisrael, He did not tell them to the goyim, and they don't know his mishpatim, halelu''ka". We are praising Him that He told us- exclusively- his laws, but not the Non-Jews. That's clear from the continuation- he gave them to us, not to them. Pshat has nothing to do with Him keeping the laws. W/o yerushalmi (or the rebbe) you would never say that's pashut pshat. If you need chazal's extrapolation to explain a pasuk, it's not the pashut pshat.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel the answer is "getting flamed". That is not my intention. My arguments are against your answer, so they're not irrelevant. I don't have a question about these sources. I have a question about your answer. As it stands, it's unsubstantiated, so that's why I don't believe it properly answers the question...I never said it did.

Comment: @Binyomin Did He tell his laws to the Avot, who kept all the commandments before they were given at HarSinai?

Comment: @robev It's a flame. The question from the OP has nothing to do with how you understand the concept of "plain meaning", whether taken simply according to the English language or if you want to try to force it into the definition as used in regard to Rashi's commentary. You wanted sources that supported how I was explaining the meaning of Tehillim 147:19. Again, not a part of the OP's question. But I provided them because already I had received 2 down votes. (none from you?) You say my statements are not "substantiated"?! All is sourced with direct citations from Tanach, Midrash and Talmud.

Comment: @YaacovDeane No, he did not tell his laws to the Avos in the same way as Klal yisrael. The Avos knew the torah, but there wasn't a revelation to them. They kept it "eino metzuve v'oseh." At har sinai, Klal Yisrael- and only we- merited for Hashem to teach us His Laws, at which point they have the full status of Torah (Including lo bashamayim hi etc.) and we are now metzuveh in the mitzvos.

Comment: `You say my statements are not "substantiated"?! All is sourced with direct citations from Tanach, Midrash and Talmud.` Nowhere do you substantiate your claim that it's forbidden, whether for Beis Din or Hashem, to judge on Shabbos. You brought a Rambam that it's forbidden to exact punishment on Shabbos, and that you aren't  allowed to conduct or discuss business. Neither of those indicate if a judge can execute justice on Shabbos.

Comment: @Binyomin Nice try, but see Ba'al HaTurim and Rashi to Bereshit 26:5. No one claimed that the Avot were commanded, like the children of Israel at Sinai. But did G-d tell His laws to the Avot? Yes. Avraham "heard" G-d's voice at the age of two. That means prophetic revelation. Midrash is full of the details. And regarding Har Sinai, the innovation for us was that we were "commanded". It wasn't that we were "taught". The Torah was taught in each generation starting from Adam HaRishon. See Mishneh Torah, Foreign Worship and Customs of the Nations, chapter 1:2 for details.

Comment: @robev What is the business of Judges who sit on the Beit Din? They investigate witnesses, deliberate cases and pass judgements. Their daily business is comprised of those actions (including speaking which is a small action like with prayer). What Orthodox Beit Din do you know that convenes and conducts their court on Shabbat?

Comment: @robev Or if you would like to consider the idea as a consequence, look at Mishneh Torah Hilchot Sanhedrin 12:4 which emphasizes that once you have a conviction, meaning a completed judgement, in a capital case, you must execute the individual that day without delay. And yet, like is cited in my answer, execution on Shabbat is expressly prohibited. So in order to avoid failure to fulfill the positive requirement of execution on the day of judgement, the court does not convene and conduct its business on Shabbat.

Comment: @yaacovdeane a court can convene for some things on Shabbos.  Hataras nedarim for instance.

Comment: @Heshy Interesting point, but just quickly looking over the subject, the general rule is that it isn’t a desirable thing to do. It is generally prohibited on Shabbat except for the need of the day or a davar mitzvah. So it seems to be more an exception to the rule than a support for the idea that a Beit Din can convene and deliberate a case and pass a judgement. Sort of like the idea that thinking about your business on Shabbat is “permissible”, but that doesn’t mean it’s desirable except for the needs of the day or a davar mitzvah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I sorry but you're reaching too much. Hashem giving the Torah to klal yisrael is a major deal. We say it in birchas hatorah- asher bachar banu mikal ha'amim vnasan lanu es toraso." In the Dayenu of the hagada, etc. What's the big deal- didn't Hashem already give the Torah to the avos? It's pashut that at Har Sinai there was a Revelation and giving of the Torah to Klal yisrael- exclusively- way above and beyond whatever the avos had. We praise and thank Hashem for this exclusive revelation constantly. I think it's pashut that even the rebbe would agree to this.

Comment: @Binyomin That the giving of the Torah at Har Sinai altered the entire universe is not a dispute. There’s no overreach. But there are many aspects of this that you aren’t mentioning which suggest you are unaware of them. And to emphasize, this has nothing to do with the question or my answer. You are off on a tangent. The giving of the Torah was open to all mankind. That is because it is the fulfillment of G-d’s original intent with the creation of Adam HaRishon. This is one of traditions that Moshe had and why the Erev Rav exists.

Comment: @Binyomin The “Bachar banu MiKol HaAmim” doesn’t mean removing us from the nations like some racist or nationalist philosophies. Rather, it means that we represent the whole of mankind, like Adam HaRishon. And that is the running theme of Vayakhel-Pikudei at the conclusion of Sefer Shemot. It is the emphasis of passing through the Yam Suf on the dry land. And we occupy this contradictory condition of Klal & Prat simultaneously which is why we are able to be “cleaved to G-d”. That is the special closeness & why we are precious.

Comment: @Binyomin And this is also the emphasis of the mitzvot of Tzitzit (with the techelet) and also Tefillin. The tzitzit are four threads doubled over. 3 are all white & 1 is half blue and half white. The blue reminds us of the Heavens above. 4 threads, 2 colors and they are a single mitzvah. 4 and 2 and 1 totals 7, meaning the 7 mitzvot of Noah. It is the cordage of the tzitzit that correspond to Israel. ציצת totals 590. The 5 double knots corresponding to the 2 Heh’s that come from Sarah bring the total to 600. And with the 13 chuliyot totals the 613 mitzvot of Israel.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I think you're going very off track. Yes, Torah was open to all mankind, Avraham figured it out, Hashem offered it to the nations at har sinai, and l'asid lavo "the world will be filled with knowledge of hashem etc." All true. But this universal message doesn't contradict the concepts that a non-jew who studies torah (other than 7mitzvos) is chayav misa, because תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה, לנו ולא להם. sanhedrin 59a (see ad. loc). We received something special, a 'morasha' called the torah, which nations didn't, and we praise Hashem for this. See psalm 147:19-20. :)

Comment: @YaacovDeane you also didn't address the other difficulties- if Hashem literally keeps the mitzvos the way that we do, then his white tefillin would be posul. If he just keeps the "general concept" but it applies differently to Him, then this point no longer serves to clarify if Hashem judges on Shabbos- maybe for him judging is not a violation even if for us it would be (as seems clear from the sources cited by the OP 's own answer.) Also- according to you that 147:19 means Hashem keeps his mitzvos (and not that he taught them to klal yisrael), what's the "pashut pshat" explanation of 147:20?